# ¿Cómo registrar la fecha actual del sistema en Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel-5, date

```
public function guardarActividad(){
        //$fechaSistema = new DateTime();    
        $date = new DateTime();                
        $oActividad = new Actividad;
        $oActividad->nombre =  $_REQUEST['nombreActividad']; 
        $oActividad->responsable = $_REQUEST["responsable"];
        $oActividad->fecha = $_REQUEST["fechaActividad"];
        $oActividad->presupuesto = $_REQUEST["txtPresupuesto"];
        $oActividad->beneficiados = $_REQUEST["numBeneficiarios"]; 
        $oActividad->tipo_id = 1;
        $oActividad->estado =1;
        //$oActividad->fechaSistema = $fechaSistema;   
        $oActividad->fechaSistema = $date->format(); 
        //$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $oActividad->save();        
        $idActividad  = $oActividad->id;    

        return $idActividad;        
}
```

**Codigo javascript**

```
$("#formNuevaActividad").submit(function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url: './registrarNuevaActividad',
        data: {
            nombreActividad: $("#nombreActividad").val(),
            responsable: $("#cboResponsable").val(),
            fechaActividad: $("#fechaActividad").val(),             
            txtPresupuesto: $("#txtPresupuesto").val(),
            numBeneficiarios : $("#numBeneficiarios").val()
        },
        success: function (response) {                                        
            if(response > 0){
                mensajito=0;                    
                Exito();
                ListarActividades();
                $("#nombreActividad").val("");
                $("#cboResponsable").val("");
                $("#fechaActividad").val("");
                $("#txtPresupuesto").val("");
                $("#numBeneficiarios").val("");

            }
        },
        error: function (response) {
                  alert("Error de Conexión");
        }
    });        
});
```

Comment: Al registrar en el formulario me sale error

Comment: ¿Puedes mostrar el resto de código? ¿De dónde viene $_REQUEST? ¿Que tipo de error te da? Por favor edita tu pregunta con algo más de información.

Comment: me sale error de conexión

Comment: ¿Es correcta la ruta? ¿ya revisaste en la pestaña network de Devtools que código entrega dicha url?

Comment: si la ruta esta bien (es laravel)

Comment: cuando le mando $date->format('d/m/Y'); a la fecha en el controlador si registra normal , pero si dejo en blando  $date->format();  me sale error

Comment: Normalmente format() necesita un parámetro de entrada, ¿por qué no te sirve `$date->formar('d/m/Y')`? ¿qué es lo que quieres hacer con la fecha?

Comment: ese si me sirve si lo registra pero solo registra dia mes año , yo quiero que registre con hora tiempo segundo tambien

Comment: si me sale error de conexion

Comment: mi pregunta fue como registrar la fecha actual del sistema , los errores se dan porque no encuentro la forma , estoy trabajando con el el orm de laravel si trabajara con procedimientos almacenados pondria getdate() y listo , pero como puedo capturar esa fecha en laravel ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para Obtener la fecha usando la clase `DateTime` (incluyendo la barra invertida) ya que si no laravel buscará la clase en el namespace actual (posiblemente controllers) pero no la encontrará obviamente, añadiendo la `\`  le indicamos a Laravel que busque en el namespaces de la **Raíz** *(Comprobado Laravel 5)*

```
$now = new \DateTime();
echo $now->format('d-m-Y H:i:s');
```

Comment: si ya me funciono ! gracias amigo creo q estaba poniendolo mal al reves y-m-d, lo probe sin el  /

Comment: que raro usando mozilla firefox si me registra bien pero el chrome me sale error de conexion

Comment: Utilizó la barra invertida? si es así es un buen punto.

Comment: si probe con y sin la barra en ambos casos firefox registra bien y chrome no, sera la cache?

Comment: Lo raro es que mis pruebas las hice en Chrome y funciona a la perfección. muy raro.

Comment: no se que ha pasado , pero tras varios intentos ya registro , estara mal algo por ahi ; gracias por todo amigo (y)

Answer (score 1):

Para trabajar con fechas en Laravel podés utilizar [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/):

Tu código sería:

```
use Carbon\Carbon;
...
public function guardarActividad(){             
    $oActividad = new Actividad;
    $oActividad->nombre =  $_REQUEST['nombreActividad']; 
    $oActividad->responsable = $_REQUEST["responsable"];
    $oActividad->fecha = $_REQUEST["fechaActividad"];
    $oActividad->presupuesto = $_REQUEST["txtPresupuesto"];
    $oActividad->beneficiados = $_REQUEST["numBeneficiarios"]; 
    $oActividad->tipo_id = 1;
    $oActividad->estado =1; 
    $oActividad->fechaSistema = Carbon::now()->toTimeString();
    $oActividad->save();        
    $idActividad  = $oActividad->id;    

    return $idActividad;        
}
```

Puedes guardar también como un objeto **Carbon** y tendrás acceso con métodos.

Comment: claro si tambien me habia buscado y me decian sobre carbon , de todas maneras si me funciono con el datime nada mas gracias de todas maneras

Comment: de nada. Es la convención más utilizada cuando hablamos de fechas en Laravel, utilizar Carbon.